# "more" command will not save to file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I am trying to delete the first 200 lines in a .txt file.

The above code has been working for months but just recently has stopped working, the code runs up to the more command then stops.

If I press the keyboard a few times it will trigger something and start moving on to the next lines of code.

I want this code to run without me manually pressing the keyboard a few times while running.

As a side note if I close the terminal window instead of forcing the script along and then try to delete the new database2.txt file, I get an error that the file cannot be deleted because it is in use by more.com.

My code:

```
cd c:\folder
more /E +200 Database.txt > Database2.txt
timeout 10
del /f Database.txt
timeout 10
rename Database2.txt Database.txt
timeout 10
exit;
```

I am running:

- Windows 10 home version 1703
- OS build: 15063.674
- Ram: 6gb
- X64 processor
- 64bit OS
- Intel core i5-2430m cpu@2.40ghz

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: If it's a text file with not more than 65534 lines, use `more +200 < Database.txt > Database2.txt`; if the file is huger, `more` awaits user input...

Comment: This I tried this and it did not stop the command from hanging. The database.txt file is less than 10,000 lines

Comment: The comand delivers the output to a database2.txt file but does not move on to the next line in the batch file. How can I force the batch script to move to the next line after creating database2.txt? It seems as though the more comand is waiting for me to press the space bar in order to complete the comand. How can I avoid this? I just need the comand to be finished after database2.txt is created

Comment: I would assume there is some weird control character in your data then. What creates the DB text file?

Comment: I create it database file manually. This script has worked before, idk it has stopped, maybe some wired windows update. I have completely reset my pc to factory settings and I am still getting the same issue. If I force the comand through with "start cmd more +200 Database.txt >database2.txt I will end up with a blank database. If I don't force it the script will wait until I press the space at twice. Really frustrated, not sure what else I can do. Is there another way to delete the first 200 lines without using the more command?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyone's help in trying to figure out my problem but I have found the solution. I formatted the comand in this way:

">Database2.txt (
More +200 Database.txt
)"

If someone could shed some light as to why this happened or how this format has fixed my problem when it is supposed to be the same command that would be great!